# Children's fantasy book where two boys enter a parallel world through the principal's office where math and poetry were magic

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

Read this as a kid in the early 80s.

Two boys in our world get in a fight at school, but when they enter the principal's office they are transported to a parallel world. As I recall, they had to work together to save that world by finding several magic items (one was a thread, I think?). And in that world math and poetry were magic?

Anyone remember this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[*The Hero From Otherwhere*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1838431.The_Hero_from_Otherwhere) by Jay Williams. 1973.

> Two boys who are enemies at school find they must rely on each other when they are transported to a strange world parallel to the one on earth.

An example cover is shown below taken from [Library Thing](http://www.librarything.com/work/537975/covers), click the link to see a couple of other ones.

[image: The Hero From Otherwhere front cover]