# Fantasy novel with two young boys who find a portal and are given a quest. Wolf on the cover

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read this paperback in the 80's. This is what I remember:

1. the main characters are two male teens/pre-teens who do not get along but need to work together.
2. They portal to another world where they are given a quest.
3. They are given spears or rods that are unbreakable and food bowls in which any type of food can appear when they wish for it.
4. One of the main characters tries to tame a wolf/wild dog towards the end.
5. One chapter has the two boys running from place to place with torches trying to light things for a ritual.
6. One chapter has the word of witch or witches in its title
7. The paperback cover has a wolf on it and other fantasy things around it
8. Upon completing the quest they humbly do not accept the monetary reward that is promised.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to remember title/author of children's fantasy book](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/39270/trying-to-remember-title-author-of-childrens-fantasy-book)

Comment: I'd leave this open as it has much more info than the duplicate.

Comment: VTLO, there's no acceptance.

Answer (score 3):

I think you might be looking for **The Hero From Otherwhere** by [*Jay Williams*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jay_Williams_(author)).

> SUMMARY: Two boys who are enemies at school find they
>   must rely on each other when they are transported to a
>   strange world parallel to the one on earth.

[image: The Hero From Otherwhere by Jay Williams Paperback cover art]

Comment: @JASONKRAUSS: If this is the right answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Comment: Besides the cover and the fact that this is about 2 boys, what about the ops other main points?

Comment: @decuser We already established points 1, 2 and 7 check out. I checked and I can confirm points 3, 4, 6 and 8 as well. Only point 5 I could not find, but I may have just been serching the wrong words.